# Group a list without redrawing the whole DOM in Polymer

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm struggling w/ a challenge that is I think a good example of the kind of thing Polymer (with its observables) makes more difficult than React.

I'm retrieving chat messages from Firebase. As they come in, I'd like to ensure they're sorted by date and I'd like for consecutive messages from the same user to be grouped together. This is so that I can print the user and picture just once when a user posts consecutive messages.

```
-- Load more --
[ ] Dave
  Message
  Message
[ ] Jane
  Message
  Message
[ ] Dave
  Message
[ Add message ]
```

This needs to handle a) the initial page of N items, b) new messages that come in and c) the "load more" that loads *older* items. It all needs to go in the correct order and group.

After several implementation attempts, here's one that, when a new item comes in (by adding new or loading more, doesn't matter), it a) sorts `items` by date, then b) groups everything by a user's consecutive messages.

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3681de332d2e965e2480

The problem: as this sorts and regroups fields that are `@observable` on every new item, adding a new message to the chat for example causes Polymer to re-draw the whole list in DOM. The user pictures actually flash, and the UI freezes for a moment. It's unacceptable.

This has been done countless times before across chat apps. What is the right (Polymer-friendly?) approach here?

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, this should only happen if you are creating an entirely new list each time any part of the list changes. If you can instead modify the existing list with only the required changes, then only the modified items should re-render.

If you could post a link to an example polymer app that is experiencing this issue that would be helpful as well.

If there are going to be a large number of items, you should probably look into using the `core-list-dart` element. It will manage rendering just the current viewport plus a buffer for you.